# Ejabberd api using subscribe room

Tags: ejabberd, ejabberd-api

In ejabberd api, i can fill user,nick,room, but how can i fill the nodes? Is there any example. Thank you.

POST /api/subscribe_room

```
{
  "user": "aaaaa",
  "nick": "bbbbb",
  "room": "ccccc",
  "nodes": "ddddd"
}
```

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
[
"aaaaa",
"bbbbb"
]

My example :

```
{
  "user":"muuser",
  "nick":"ccccdd",
  "room":"myRoom",
  "nodes": ["urn:xmpp:mucsub:nodes:presence","urn:xmpp:mucsub:nodes:messages","urn:xmpp:mucsub:nodes:affiliations","urn:xmpp:mucsub:nodes:subject", "urn:xmpp:mucsub:nodes:config","urn:xmpp:mucsub:nodes:system"] 
}
```

Comment: I was able to get messages by sending the json like this : "nodes": "urn:xmpp:mucsub:nodes:messages" ,, for multi node still searching

Answer (score 1):

as explained [here](https://www.ejabberd.im/forum/28780/api-subscribe-room)
nodes attribute  is filled like so :

```
nodes : "urn:xmpp:mucsub:nodes:messages,urn:xmpp:mucsub:nodes:affiliations"
```